# Ember CLI Ignores all coffeescript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-cli

I've created a new app using Ember CLI

I have already run `npm install ember-cli-coffeescript` but when I convert files to coffeescript Ember does not recognize them. For example when I add a custom route .coffee file:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    controller.set('title', "My App")
```

and create an index.hbs:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

The dom renders with an empty h1 tag.

When I convert app.js to app.coffee:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
`import Resolver from 'ember/resolver'`
`import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers'`
`import config from './config/environment'`

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true

App = Ember.Application.extend
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver


loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix)

`export default App`
```

The page does not load and I get "Uncaught Error: Could not find module app-name/app "

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was was with my initial command:

```
npm install ember-cli-coffeescript
```

should be:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-coffeescript
```

While the first command appears to do something it isn't the right thing. Don't forget the `--save-dev` flag